# Issue loading XML into DIV using JavaScript in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, load, internet-explorer-9

I need to load a configuration XML into a DIV, for that I'm using the following code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
                    console.log("Document ready");
        $("#footer_config").load("/config/footer_config.xml");
    });
```

This code works ok in Chrome but it doesn't in IE. It prints "Document ready" in the console but the "footer_config" DIV is empty. If I press CTRL+F5 in IE it works and the div has the content of the XML file. I'm using IE 9.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try it without the console.log ?

Comment: Yes, at first it didin't have the console.log, I put it there to check if the $(document).ready was being executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    console.log("Document ready");
    $("#footer_config").load('/config/footer_config.xml', function() {
        console.log('Load finished');
    });
});
```

This will tell you that the load is complete. Try checking the network tab in the Chrome developer tools afterwards to see if it was even pulled down.

Update:

Instead of using the load method, try pulling it down with the AJAX method:

```
$.ajax({url: '/config/footer_config.xml', dataType: 'xml', cache: false, success: function(d) {
    console.log(d);
    $('#footer_config').html($(d).html();
}});
```

Comment: How exactly does one go about checking the Chrome developer tools in Internet Explorer, as that is the only browser it fails in ?

Comment: You could check the server log to see if the URL was accessed.

Comment: I tried with the console.log('Load finished'). It prints "Load finished" but it doesn't load the XML into the DIV. This only ocurrs when the page is cached. If I clean the cache the DIV is loaded with the XML

Comment: Sorry, I meant the F12 developer tools in IE.

Comment: Thanks! This is how I solved it, making an ajax call and specifying the "cache" setting to false. Thanks for your help.